# Getting iframe URL using Scala/Lift

Tags: html, scala, lift

all. I am working on a Scala/Lift web application that uses an iframe to display content from another web application hosted on the same domain. Is there a way to access the URL of the child frame's currently-displayed page? The suggested solutions found for the general problem typically use Javascript, but I would to like accomplish this with Scala if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this would be possible, presuming you are trying to read the current page that it is on rather than the page that is sent by default.

If you are trying to read the current page it is on then that would necessitate interaction between the server and the client, meaning you would have to use some javascript. If you are trying to find the page it was on originally then that should have been set earlier in your program so you will be able to just store that value in a variable and access it later.

If you clarified which you were trying to do you might get a more complete answer.